# How do I go about extracting only relevant JSON data from this web service

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api

So I need to implement an external web service to include remote data, combined with my own local data, of various events in the United Kingdom. These events will be produced upon a search of keywords, such as name or date. I'm going to use the eventful api, and this is what I have found:

```
  Javascript Sample page <br>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.eventful.com/js/api">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function show_alert()
  {
    var oArgs = {
              app_key:"MY APP KEY",
              id: "20218701",
              page_size: 25 ,
    };
    EVDB.API.call("/events/get", oArgs, function(oData) {
        // Note: this relies on the custom toString() methods below    });
        alert("your myObject is " + JSON.stringify(oData) );
    });

  }
  function show_alert2()
  {
     var oArgs = {
        app_key: "MY APP KEY",
        q: "music",
        where: "United Kingdom", 
        "date": "2013061000-2015062000",
        page_size: 5,
        sort_order: "popularity",
     };
     EVDB.API.call("/events/search", oArgs, function(oData) {
        // Note: this relies on the custom toString() methods below
        alert("your myObject is " + JSON.stringify(oData));
      });
  }
  </script>
```

So for example, when the alert is called I get a long string of JSON data relating to that hardcoded search.

My question is how do I extract only the relevant data from that long string? Here's an example string:

https://pastebin.com/gdHZdQT9

I only want core data, such as the events name, description, date, and the venue name, town, and postcode.

UPDATED:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.eventful.com/js/api">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">    

  function show_alert2()
  {
     var oArgs = {
        app_key: "MY KEY",
        q: "music",
        where: "United Kingdom", 
        "date": "2013061000-2015062000",
        page_size: 5,
        sort_order: "popularity",
     };
     EVDB.API.call("/events/search", oArgs, function(oData) {
        // Note: this relies on the custom toString() methods below
        //alert("your myObject is " + JSON.stringify(oData));
        let obj = JSON.stringify(oData);
        return obj;
        //var data = oData; 
      });
  } 

  function simplifyObject(obj){
  return obj.events.event.map((x) => { return { title: x.title, description: x.description, date: x.start_time, venue_name: x.venue_name, venue_address: x.venue_address, postal_code: x.postal_code } });
  }
  var result = simplifyObject(obj);//result is an array of objects
  console.log(result[0].title);//for 1st object's title
  </script>
```

Current search code:

My initial thought was to do a onkeydown="show_alert2()"> which triggers the function above to produce the var result.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" onkeydown="show_alert2()">
  <div class="panel-heading" ng-init="getEvents()">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Latest events</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search for events, venues, or dates" size="40">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="event in events | filter:search">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h4>{{event.title}}</h4>
                    <p>{{event.desc}}</p>
            <p>{{event.venue.name}}</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#!/events/details/{{event._id}}">View event</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img class="thumbnail" src="{{event.venue.icon}}">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: write a function which takes in your api data and returns an object with your relevant data

Comment: Okay so for my own data I have the event object, and I return the specific data by doing event.name etc... Does that work the same here?

Comment: You see the JSON data I linked? How do I return event with a certain event.title? If you see the title parameter

Comment: You can do is `let obj=JSON.stringify(oData);`, then access it like `obj.title`

Comment: Okay, but do you know how I do it with this particular JSON data? If you see the format is { "events": {"event":[ <data>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this,

```
var obj = JSON.parse(oData);
function simplifyObject(obj){
  return obj.events.event.map((x) => { return { title: x.title, description: x.description, date: x.start_time, venue_name: x.venue_name, venue_address: x.venue_address, postal_code: x.postal_code } });
}
var result = simplifyObject(obj);//result is an array of objects
console.log(result[0].title);//for 1st object's title
```

Comment: Sorry its got to be `JSON.parse` instead of stringify. A typo from my side. Sorry :(

Comment: What is the `typeof(oData)`? If its object then you don't need to `JSON.parse` it.

Comment: Thanks so much. You've been of so much help! Can i just ask literally one more thing. How can I implement the result variable into my search function already? I currently have a search function that just filters the local events, after getEvents() is called. What's the simplest way of also through var result? I've added in my current code. Cheers

Comment: I don't know angular for that :(

Comment: If you could add your js function doing the search, that may help like `app.filter()` or something

Comment: Don't worry at all! Thank you so much for your help :)